# Datepicker never works on initial page load

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Using this date picker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I am using it in a bootstrap modal so this is how I call it:

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    alert("datepicker ready...");
     $("#datepicker").datetimepicker();
})
```

And here it is in the form:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Extraction.DateExtracted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Extraction.DateExtracted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Extraction.DateExtracted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

The "alert" fires every time I open the modal (good) but I have to refresh the page and reopen the modal for the datepicker to work.

Scripts seems to be in order:

[image]

Comment: why don't you just fire it on the button you use to open the modal so that it fires everytime that way?

Comment: That's weird, it never haeppened to mw using .net MVC it's working for me on my project and on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/William_/20oywuno/13/ trying to duplicate what you put on razor, shound't give any error. Could it be that file is not being loaded in that moment?

Comment: Seems to only happen in Chrome. Using version: 60.0.3112.78 .

Comment: @BattlFrog this seems to be an error only for that version as Version 62.0.3202.62 (Build oficial) (64 bits) seems to not having any problem with it

Comment: I updated my chrome version, it did not change.  I then put a test datepicker on a regular view (not a partial in a modal) and it works every time, so I guess it has something to do with being in the modal.

Comment: @BattlFrog you can always try to call the plugin using document instead of body that way on the parent view the script will take the partial without problem, or at least it should

Comment: @William - I decided the problem had to do with trying to use it in the modal/partial view so I went to a different datepicker that allowed me to call using an HTML data- tag, and that is working.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess, it's because either your js files are out of order or you have duplicate files which causes it to break. Check here to see if you have them all in order:

https://jsfiddle.net/rd8nnLg5/1/

```
    $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
```

Comment: I mean it works there, you must have a missing file or a double